# How to write efficient app tutorials iOS

Tags: ios

I would like to add instructions on how to use the app the first time the user logs in. I realize that this requires a lot of UI and coding work. My question is: Since the code will only be run at most one time, is there a more efficient way of adding it in other than adding it like normal UI and code? Do I mix the code for the ViewControllers together? Won't this get confusing? Won't it take up storage that is essentially pointless after the first 5 minutes?

Any tips on creating a tutorial on a separate level, over the code of the actual app would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way of doing intro tutorial is to use [`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html).

It's the pages you swipe , with the little dots at the bottom.

To track if it is the first time the user launch the app, use [`NSUserDefault`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) and set a boolean flag.

See this tutorial:

[**How to Use UIPageViewController to Build Tutorial Screens**](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)